# Typescript JSON returns undefined values

Tags: json, typescript, local-storage

I am creating an object in Typescript in this way:

```
var map = {};
map["id"] = 1;
map["name"] = "ABC";
```

I am then adding this object to localStorage using this function:

```
set(key: string, value: any): boolean {
      this.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
      return true;
  }
```

With the `key` being the `id` and the `value` being the entire object.

After I have multiple entries in my localStorage, I want to extract them all at once so I tried using two ways:

1.

```
return Object.values(this.localStorage);
```

2. 

```
var values:any = [],
    keys = Object.values(this.localStorage),
    i = keys.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        values.push(this.localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
    }
    return values;
```

By using either, when I try to access each map individually, all the values are undefined like this:

```
{id: undefined, name: undefined}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can store only strings in local storage, so you could `JSON.stringify` the object before storing it and deserialize after get

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you!